# Python-Pandas : I would like groupby user and date in range(-7) days

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

### I looking for the amount of user in date range(-7) from pandas dataframe

Example.

| UserID | Date (Y/M/D) |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021/02/15 |
| 100 | 2021/02/10 |
| 100 | 2021/02/8 |
| 101 | 2021/02/10 |
| 102 | 2021/02/15 |
| 103 | 2021/02/10 |

What should I start I want receive result like it

| UserID | Date (Y/M/D) | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021/02/15 | 3 ## Because date (15 - 7) is 8 in dataframe it have 3 row in range 15 - 8 |
| 100 | 2021/02/10 | 2 ## Because date (10 - 7) is 3 in dataframe it have 2 row in range 10 - 3 |
| 100 | 2021/02/8 | 1 |
| 101 | 2021/02/10 | 1 |
| 102 | 2021/02/15 | 1 |
| 103 | 2021/02/10 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom lambda function:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Date (Y/M/D)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date (Y/M/D)'])

#7 days timedelta
t = pd.Timedelta(7, unit='d')

#for each group counts values between previous 7 days and original
f = lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: (x.between(y - t, y).sum()))
df['new'] = df.groupby('UserID')['Date (Y/M/D)'].apply(f)
print (df)
   UserID Date (Y/M/D)  new
0     100   2021-02-15    3
1     100   2021-02-10    2
2     100   2021-02-08    1
3     101   2021-02-10    1
4     102   2021-02-15    1
5     103   2021-02-10    1
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your *Date* column from string to datetime (if you
didn't do it before):

```
df['Date (Y/M/D)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date (Y/M/D)'])
```

Then take only rows from last 7 days:

```
df[df['Date (Y/M/D)'] >= pd.Timestamp.today().normalize() - pd.offsets.Day(7)]
```

And to generate *Count* column, run:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('UserID', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(len(x) - np.arange(len(x)), x.index))
```

The result is:

```
   UserID Date (Y/M/D)  Count
0     100   2021-02-15      3
1     100   2021-02-10      2
2     100   2021-02-08      1
3     101   2021-02-10      1
4     102   2021-02-15      1
5     103   2021-02-10      1
```